# Determine the distribution function of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that (X,Y) has density function

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{(1+x+y)^3}\quad x,y\gt0 \quad$$

Determine the distribution of

(a) X + Y

(b) X − Y

My attempt at solving (a):
$$U=X+Y,V=Y$$
$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(u-v,v)|J|=\frac{2}{(1+u-v+v)^3}*1=\frac{2}{(1+u)^3}$$
$$f_{U}(u)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)dv=\frac{2v}{(1+u)^3}$$

Answer in the book is $\frac{2u}{(1+u)^3}$

My attempt at solving (b):
$$U=X-Y,V=Y$$
$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(u+v,v)|J|=\frac{2}{(1+u+v+v)^3}*1=\frac{2}{(1+u+2v)^3}$$
$$f_{U}(u)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)dv=\frac{-1}{2(2v+u+1)^2}$$

Answer in the book is $\frac{1}{2(1+|u|)^2}$

What did i do wrong? any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: The Jacobian determinants are good, and the choice for variable substitutions okay, but those *should not* be *indefinite* integrals. $~$ You need to consider the support for $Y$ *relative* to the other variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to the bounds of the integrals.   They are not indefinite.   Where do your $U,V$ "live"?

The support for $(X,Y)$ is $\{(x,y): 0<x, 0<y\}$

So setting $U=X+Y$, then the support for $(U,Y)$ is $\{(u,y): 0<y<u\}$ .   Because is $X$ is strictly positive then surely: $Y<X+Y$ .   Thus you must have:

$$f_U(u)=\int_{0}^u \frac 2{(1+(u-y)+y)^3}\mathsf d y=\dfrac{2u}{(1+u)^3}$$

Likewise setting $V=X-Y$, then the support for $(V,Y)$ is $\{(v,y):0< y, -y<v\}$.

$$f_V(v) = \int_{\max\{0,-v\}}^\infty \dfrac{2}{(1+(v+y)+y))^3}\mathsf d y$$

So...